# Use Appengine Channel API with DART

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, channel-api

Is it possible to use Google Appengine Channel API with DART language? It would be great if you can point to some examples and pitfalls if any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I've recommended is to use the Channel API in JS to open a socket and forward all messages via a postMessage or a custom event, and receive them in Dart.

I'm not sure if any generic solution has been open sourced, but it should be fairly trivial to do, and doesn't require general JS-interop to work.

edit: clarified

edit 2:

FYI: I just published a library to do exactly this. I hope it works for you!

http://code.google.com/p/gae-channel-api-dart/

Answer (score 3):

A guy from the Dart team ported a client library to Dart: http://code.google.com/p/gae-channel-api-dart/

Comment: This likely to break in the future. See my answer.

Comment: Yes, but considering the fact that he works for Google, it makes sense to rely on him to fix it if it does break.

Comment: @PeterKnego, I didn't port the Channel API JS, I wrap it ,so it won't break. At least not because the channel implementation changes. It's broken because of Dart language and API changes though. I try to keep up with those.

Answer (score 3):

The JS code of the Channel API is proprietary and there is no "source" (well there is but good luck [reverse-engineering that](https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js)). Google does this on purpose, so that they can change the Channels underlying protocol without messy upgrade/deprecation process.

So if you follow @Shannon's suggestion, the rewritten code is likely to stop working at some point in the future and you will need to repeat the process of reverse-engineering the Channels JS code.

A better solution would be to call Channels API JS code from Dart, but at the moment [Darts support for calling JS is rudimentary](http://blog.dartwatch.com/2012/06/dart-javascript-interoperability-coming.html), but is seems that they are [already started working on improving it](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=625).